# Cannot use current user from custom authentication in a query (ORACLE APEX)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have implemented a custom authentication scheme to log in to an Apex application but now I don't know how to get the current user from the account that logs in.

I need this to compare the current user to a username in a table to show the appropriate information for that user.

I can get the username as a static value in a text field using the code `:&APP_USER.` but cannot use it in a PL/SQL query.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your syntax is a little odd - try just using `:APP_USER` in your queries. See docs: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#BEIHCJBG

Comment: Which version of APEX? as of APEX 5 you can use `SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER')` from within SQL and PL/SQL to get the current application user. Jeff Kemp [blogged](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2015/11/apex-5-application-context/) on this a while ago.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that you can't use APP_USER in a PL/SQL query. Because, I can.

Comment: *"... but cannot use it in a PL/SQL query"* - please show us what you tried, and what occurred as a result.